# ASP.Net Core 6.0 warnings: The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a nullable annotations context

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

I am following the MvcMovie tutorial for ASP.Net Core 6 at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

It says, "to eliminate the warnings from nullable references types, remove the following line from the MvcMovie.csproj file:"

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

I have done this but everytime I build I get these messages.  And I have the green squiggly with the warning in the Movie POCO file.

It gives me this warning:
The annotation for nullable reference types should only be used in code within a nullable annotations context.

I submitted the issue on the tutorial page as a git issue.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this in ASP.Net Core 6?  I haven't come accross this in any previous versions. [image]